# issue with tee command and a script

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

im trying to use tee command with rendercheck tests on ubuntu 15.04, tee command works fine with 6 tests of rendercheck for example :

```
 ./rendercheck -t fill,dcoords,scoords,mcoords,tscoords,tmcoords | tee summary
```

but if i added other more , example :

```
 ./rendercheck -t fill,dcoords,scoords,mcoords,tscoords,tmcoords,composite | tee summary
```

the output does not shows in terminal and the file summary does not contain nothing, so im not sure why i have this behavior with tee command, it would be great if someone can help me, thanks

Comment: what happens if you run it without `tee`? from your question it sounds like there is no output which would mean it's not a `tee` problem

Comment: If i run without tee i have the output of rendenderchek tools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"composite" test opens a graphic window, doesn't display text to standard output.

I guess you'll obtain the same behavior if you just execute:

```
rendercheck composite | tee summary
```

Regards

Comment: thanks, this answer i help much to understand rendercheck tests